# I paid for an airline ticket, I took the flight, but NEVER got charged

Tags: contract-law

I purchased an airline ticket, paid in full on my VISA, and took the flight.

But the charge NEVER showed up on my VISA.

The card has expired.

Now, 4 months later, the travel agency is demanding the money.

I am wondering If I need to pay? What does the LAW say about this?

Thanks.

---

Thank you guys for the comments.

I live in Canada. The agency that sold the ticket is in the Netherland, and the ticket was purchased online in Thailand, so the jurisdiction is not clear.

I am new here, I think the "law" section is more appropriate but I have no idea how to move the question.

Of course if I purchase a service and use it, I should pay for it. However, in this case there is an important "time component" attached.

The ticket is a #3000, and at the time I purchased it, I had the money available and ready to pay for it. I purchased it believing I will be billed immediately, and it is on the travel agency that they did not bill me.

Now, 4.5 months after the fact, the necessary cash is not available, the purchase itself was attached to a certain point in time, not months later.

It is not reasonable for me to put $3000 on hold in case one day sometime in the future they decide to bill me, after 30 days, I assumed I will never hear from them.

Anyway, I decided to to what I think is the right thing, and offered to pay half, right away, to settle this issue, providing they reply to my email with "we confirm that half the payment will be considered payment in full, and this matter will be considered closed", surprisingly, they thanked me for my offer, but did not confirm this will end the issue.

Comment: Please add the **jurisdiction** you are asking about.

Comment: I can't image a jurisdiction where claims expire by limitiation already within a few months. If you bought and even used a service, what makes you think that you should not have to pay for it?

Comment: I would move this to Law Stack Exchange if it had the required details for that site. But without jurisdiction it will be rejected there.

Comment: Try [money.se]. They already have questions like this.

Comment: Highly likely you have a legal duty to pay based on the T&C when you booked the flight. Irrespective of the card expiry, I think it’s possible that if the travel agency claimed the debt direct from your card issuer they would be obliged to honour the payment, since you did authorise it in the first place and your old and new cards are linked to the same account

Comment: Well, @Tor-EinarJarnbjo summarized the situation well. You signed up for a service and then used that service. After making absolutely certain that you didn't pay already, you should do the right thing and pay your bill.

Comment: Thank you guys for the comments.

Comment: Yes, you'll have to pay.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie But if they agree that you'll only have to pay half, then it seems like you'll only have to pay half. I don't know the exact law on this situation, but if I've been short some amount of money in the past at some small retailers, and sometimes that retailer will agree that if I pay some smaller amount, that the bill will be settled. If we both agreed to that, then I don't think she can come back later and still claim that I must pay the rest of the full amount at some later date.

Comment: @Brandin There would have to be an agreement in place. Some sort of mistake with billing does not constitute an agreement.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie I was referring to the e-mail exhange and offer to pay half. If they eventually agree to that, then it seems that would constitute an agreement.

Answer (score 6):

You entered into two contracts, one with a Canadian travel agency and on with an airline (maybe multiple airlines). The travel agency acted as your agent, in securing the booking with the airline. In each case, the contract reduces to the promise "I will give you this in exchange for that". The other parties did what they were supposed to do, now you are legally required to pay up.

It is highly unlikely that your agreements included a clause to the effect that if they don't get the money from you within a particular short time-frame, the ticket is free. There can be a statutory limit on how long a civil claim (unpaid debt) is valid, but that is measured in years, not months.

You can certainly negotiate with the party seeking payment (I assume it is the travel agency). If the agency clearly, unambiguously and explicitly states that they will accept half payment to settle the debt, then if they try to sue you in court, you can produce that email plus proof of payment as evidence that there is no debt. Thanking you for an offer is not
clear, unambiguous and explicit acceptance of half payment.

Answer (score -4):

Consumers have rights, and expectations. As a consumer, when I go online and buy an airline ticket, input my valid credit card, and click "buy", it is understood the ticket has been paid. Without the payment, NO online company will provide you with a ticket. It is perfectly reasonable for me to assume as a consumer that this ticket has been paid in full. If the seller has a "glitch", it is THE SELLER's problem.  When I buy a ticket "Now" and pay "now" there is no expectation that I will need to pay for it several months down the road.  I therefore feel strongly that the seller has to bare a big chunk of the responsibility, I paid, in full, on time, at the time of purchase, they just did not collect.

Comment: Under principles of contract law, it is **not** the sellers obligation to ensure the payment is made to them. It is the buyer's obligation to uphold their end of the bargain, e.g. Pay the bill.